# What does it mean in bash [ "abc" < $bar ]?

Tags: bash

Currently, I am learning bash. I wonder what the `[ "abc" < $bar ]` command means. I know that `[]` compares or tests their values. But how does the `<` operator work between `abc` string and `$bar` variable Can you please describe it?

Comment: `<` is the input redirection operator. So this is reading input from the filename `$bar]`

Comment: I doubt that's the actual code. When you use `[]` you have to have spaces around them. Please post a [mre].

Comment: The `["abc"` would  just result in  `bash: [abc: command not found`. There is a command named `[`, there has to be a space after `[`. Please copy the command exactly. Please confirm if there is `[` or `[[` or `((`, characters matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ "abc" < $bar ]` looks like an error by the programmer. We can rewrite it to `[ "abc" ] < $bar` with exactly the same meaning.

`<` is a redirection operator to read the input from a file named `$bar`. `[` command ignores standard input, so any input is ignored. If `$bar` variable is empty, it will write a `bash: $bar: ambiguous redirect` message.

Then `[ "abc" ]` checks if `abc` is a non-empty string. It is not an empty string, so `[ "abc" ]` returns with zero exit status meaning success.

If the author of the code meant to compare strings lexicographically, he should have written `[[ "abc" < "$bar" ]]`. The `[` command does not support `<` operator (see [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), in fact POSIX mentions that it is not included.). In Bash, `[ "abc" '<' "$bar" ]` would work, because `[` is a builtin aliased to `test` (see output of `help [`), and the builtin `test` command does implement the string comparison operators `<` and `>`. But `/usr/bin/[ a '<' b ]` command results in `/usr/bin/[: ‘<’: binary operator expected`. `[` *external command* does not support `<`.

Additionally, `$bar` is not quoted, so the result of `$bar` undergoes word splitting and filename expansion, which looks like another error. Remember to check your script by shellcheck .

```
[ "abc" < $bar ]
        ^-- SC2073 (error): Escape \< to prevent it redirecting (or switch to [[ .. ]]).
          ^--^ SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Comment: Also, quoting the `<` prevents it from being interpreted as the input redirection operator, in addition to the `bash` built-in supporting `<` as an operator in the first place.